# Frequent Issues With Importing National Bank of Ukraine API Data into R

Tags: r, json, rest, jsonlite

I am trying to access data from the [National Bank of Ukraine's api](https://bank.gov.ua/ua/open-data/api-dev) using R, but it does not seem to work when I try to make custom API calls.

Just as an example, here is code I can use to import the monthly survey of enterprises in Ukraine data for August 2019—which is the default example [call under section 18 of the NBU's api dev website](https://bank.gov.ua/ua/open-data/api-dev)

```
library("jsonlite")
fromJSON("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/survey?period=m&date=20190801&json")
```

This works as intended—I am able to get the data for August 2019. But if I try any other month I seem to get and error or are timed-out (I am guessing because the API call is wrong, but I can't figure out why).

```
library("jsonlite")
fromJSON("https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/survey?period=m&date=20190901&json")
```

This does not work for me, and neither does removing the date/period specification
I have tried a number of other specifications and data sets but they all seemingly have the same problem—the NBU's example links work fine, but anything custom that I try doesn't work.

Am I making a mistake here or is there an issue with the database?

Comment: My guess: the first query works because a rev-proxy is working and it is caching 20190801; and the others are not working because the backend is failing. Just a guess.

Comment: Gotcha, that's what I was worried about. It's interesting because some of the databases seem to be working and being updated (e.x., here's an interest rate one that was updated Tuesday: https://bank.gov.ua/NBU_uonia?id_api=UONIA_UnsecLoansDepo&json) so I was hoping it was just a mistake on my end